# Same data in HighCharts and HighStock

Tags: highcharts

I used the same data both in HighCharts and HighStock, but it show different result. How can I fix this problem or I have to use HighCharts?

I want that the HighStock chart can be the same with Highcharts.

HighStock Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lyplba/7eLfu7u3/1/

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

HighCharts Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lyplba/6wnv8mk8/

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

Comment: Your chart options have duplicate properties that set different options. Your highstock chart is set to show 'percent' compare. Try starting from identical properties and then switch chart type. Also recommend to turn of highstock `dataGrouping`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highstock contains Highcharts within it, so you can use `Highcharts.chart` constructor instead of `Highcharts.stockChart` in your Highstock example (`<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>` used).

Also make sure that the same options are being passed to both charts (as @wergeld suggested).